# Should I Learn NHaml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#, haml, nhaml

Should I learn [NHaml](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/)?

What does it provide me over a classic ASP.NET MVC view? What are the pros and cons?

Are you using it via the [MVC Contrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib/Wiki/View.aspx?title=NHaml&referringTitle=Documentation) project?

I have been seeing more and more about it. For example... I saw a blog post by [Matthew Podwysocki](http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2008/10/06/asp-net-mvc-with-nhaml-f-edition.aspx) using ASP.NET MVC, NHaml, and F#!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should only take a few hours if you're familiar with the MVC framework, so I'd say yes, learn it. NHaml is a compact way to write HTML code. It is pretty easy to read and write once you get used to it. The downsides are that you lose the ASP.NET controls, so server-side processing is more difficult. Your team may be resistant, too.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, learning NHAML is really easy and it is much easier to write than the web forms syntax.